# Identify the group of a Regex Match in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a fairly large regular expression in QT that matches multiple patterns... to simplify the problem I have this regex:

`QRegularExpression regex = ("(?P<ZipCode>\d{5})|(?P<emailAddress>\w+@\w+\.\w+)|(?P<PhoneNumber>\d{3}\-\d{5,8})");`

To match a 5-digit zip code, an email address or to match a phone number in this format: 888-8888888 (I do not have tested the regex, but it's for demonstrational purposes, I don't care if it's wrong or not).

Now I need to extract from the string **in order** those information so I use this code:

`QRegularExpressionMatchIterator regexIterator = regex.globalMatch("067-839405 Junk my.email@email.com Other Junk 87494 my.email2@email.co.uk");`

and a simple while loop.

As you have noticed I named the groups in my regex. In the while loop how can I identify if the match I'm currently looking at is a ZipCode, an email address or a phone number?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#namedCaptureGroups

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html#captured

Iterate through the list of `captured()` strings and through the `namedCaptureGroups()` at the same time, and if the `captured(i)` string is not null, look at the `namedCaptureGroups().at(i)` for the same index.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I've solved the problem: maybe a slow solution, but acceptable as I don't have so many groups (not more than 40 I'm sure).